# What's the difference beween ordinary and "-src" pypy versions in pyenv?

Tags: python, pypy, pyenv

I want to install several versions of `pypy` for testing using `pyenv`. I wonder what is the difference betweeen versions of `pypy` like

```
pypy2-5.6.0
```

and

```
pypy2-5.6.0-src
```

Which ones should I install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pypy2-5.6.0` is installed as a binary, while `pypy2-5.6.0-src` is built from source by `pyenv`. [Building PyPy from source](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/build.html) is going to take **much** more time than simply downloading a binary.

See also the corresponding shell scripts in `$(pyenv root)/plugins/python-build/share/python-build`:

- [pypy2-5.6.0](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/v1.2.11/plugins/python-build/share/python-build/pypy2-5.6.0)
- [pypy2-5.6.0-src](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/v1.2.11/plugins/python-build/share/python-build/pypy2-5.6.0-src)